# How to show a comfirmation dialog when a batch file window is closed

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

When users click the close (X) button of a batch file window, I want it to show a confirmation dialog asking "Are you sure want to close this batch file?" with Yes/No options. How can I do this?

Comment: So if you already have a batch that does what you want to make a batch do, the answer is right there in the batch that you have.

Comment: @EBGreen I meant when the user clicks the "X" button

Comment: See **pause** and **choice** for the CMD prompt.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You when the user presses the red "X" button on the top right corner of the batch file, I want the batch file to comfirm the closing of the batch file.

Comment: [How to run a batch command when closing a batch script by clicking close button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11967419)

Comment: Not possible. See the SO post linked to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other great options than using a batch file for your purpose, but since you want it that way, here is the code
    `@echo off
Call :YesNoBox "Are you sure you want to do that?"
if "%YesNo%"=="7" (
Call :MessageBox "You answered NO" "Heading"
exit /b
)`
**Code for invoking the message box**

`exit /b
:YesNoBox
REM returns 6 = Yes, 7 = No. Type=4 = Yes/No
set YesNo=
set MsgType=4
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo wscript.echo msgbox(WScript.Arguments(0),%MsgType%,WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do set YesNo=%%a
exit /b`

**The above code is for programming the YesNo Options**

`:MessageBox
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo msgbox WScript.Arguments(0),0,WScript.Arguments(1) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"
exit /b`

**The above code is for setting up and programming the Message Window**

Hope it helps, but if you further want to refer for your purpose you should visit these links :  [1st Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530293/adding-vbs-yes-no-box-code-to-a-batch-file), [2nd Link](http://scripts.dragon-it.co.uk/scripts.nsf/docs/batch-gui-yesno-messagebox!OpenDocument&ExpandSection=2&BaseTarget=East&AutoFramed)

Thanks!!!

Comment: How will this help if the user closes the cmd window by clicking the 'X' button?

Comment: This is definitely not the idea in the code.. The code is solely aimed at creating a window which prompts the user for the option for closing the batch operation

Comment: I know, but that's not the OP's requirement so this clearly won't help.

Comment: Ya, you are right. Thats why I have provided a similar code not the exact working one and backed them up with references so that if the links die the code will be there for reference. Although I am working on the exact solution, will be posting it soon.

Comment: mistakenly posted as an aswer from the android app. Will delete it soon Sorry

Comment: If you know of an actual solution, do share it with all of us.

Comment: definitely will do.. Working on it